# Which component would be the right one

Tags: angular, reactjs, angular-material, frontend, material-ui

Hello I'm building a small app that connects to an api via Nodejs and store all the posts in mongodb that part is fine I already completed it BUT now I need to do the front-end part on which the user should be able to see a page with a list of the posts I have saved on the database, now the thing that is giving me hard time is should I use a table or should I use a list? I ask this bcs if you take a look at the picture you will see each row has a title an author and to the right  the date plus if you hover the row a delete button should come up... So I'm looking for suggestions should I use list or table and more importantly how can I adjust each row so I can put title author and date like in the picture? Last but not least it has to be done in Angular Material or React + Material UI. [wireframe web image](https://ibb.co/BsNHVgV)

Comment: Any framework and library will do.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother trying to fit that in a table. Instead, create a separate component representing the post, something like `PostComponent` which accepts as an `@Input()` a post and then in your parent component, where you are getting the array of posts use something like this in it's template:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor='let post of posts>
 <app-post [post]='post'></app-post>
</ng-container>
```

Now, for the layout, i suggest using the built in `display:grid` which seems like would do the job for your needs.

Comment: thank you but when i use list the row is like: Titleauthordate and i can't separate each one as in the wireframe

Comment: @CarlosDelgado, i've created astackblitz that may help you. I think it's pretty similar to your wireframe( for one row ) and could be a starting point for your app. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dx5pr

Answer (score 0):

According to your wireframe you can easily get away with a list. Apply relevant styling to your HTML components and you can achieve this. Angular data binding will help you with removing the particular object(row) from the list.

You can get some idea from this documentation
https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview

But keep in mind using a table is also a one solution but according to the wireframe it's not necessary as it's just some dynamic rows it seems.